# how to find a particular value from a string in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

how do you find a particular value from a string in ASP?

```
dim temp="alpha,bravo,charlie"
```

how do i find if 'alpha' exists in temp?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `instr` to check for the string.

For more instructions follow this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/Vbscript/func_instr.asp

Comment: Updated link: [https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Instr is good for quick solutions, if your strins is BIG or you have to use thisoften you are better off met converting the string to an array an dthen use filter to find teh value

so

```
dim temp, aTemp
temp="alpha,bravo,charlie" 
aTemp = split(temp,",")
aFound = Filter(aTemp , "alpha") ' aFound (0) contains "alpha" or is an empty array if not found.
```

Grtz